# docker-compose fails to add nuget github source

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, nuget, github-package-registry

I am working on a .NET Core web application in Visual Studio 2022.

I have a nuget package on my github and I am trying to add the github page as a source. I have generated my github PAT and authorized it, and added the package url in package sources:

> https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MyGithub/index.json

However, when I run `docker-compose`, it fails with the message

> failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed
> running [/bin/sh -c dotnet nuget add source --username
> USERNAME_NOT_REQUIRED --password $GITHUB_PACKAGE_PAT
> --store-password-in-clear-text --name github_mygithub_om_registry "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MyGithub/index.json"]: exit code: 1 If
> the error persists, try restarting Docker Desktop

It seems to be related to a local setting, because other team members are able to build the project, and we have the same docker config settings.

Comment: Are you using this for nuget restore inside the dockerfile?

Comment: @LukeBriner Yes

Comment: There shouldn't be anything local that is relevant if you have checked out the same code, although one possibility is a file that is ignored by git but included in docker. The other possibility is that you have a valid access key but it doesn't have the correct permissions? If you run up a container with just the SDK, you could exec into it and run the commands directly, that way you might see more of the actual error.